# Is there a way to bypass printf errors on different compilers?

Tags: c++, printf, c++14, c++-chrono

I have the following line of code:

```
printf("\n\nTime taken for simulation: %ld milliseconds\n", duration.count() );
```

On my home machine, I get the error,

```
main.cpp:292:65: error: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000>>::rep' (aka 'long long') [-Werror,-Wformat]
```

This error is sorted out if I change %ld to %lld
I use `g++ -std=c++14`. Home compiler version is:

```
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

On the linux cluster I operate, if run it with %lld, I get the following error,

```
main.cpp:229:83: error: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000> >::rep {aka long int}’ [-Werror=format=]
```

I use `g++ -std=c++14`. Cluster compiler version is:

```
g++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

if I change %lld to %ld, it is all good.

Is there a way I can print out duration.count(), where duration is defined as
`auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds> (stop-start);`
where stop, start are variables of type specified by `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();`.

Any advice you have would be appreciated.

Comment: The idiomatic C++ way is to not use `printf`, but rather use `std::cout`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `printf` instead of `std::cout <<`?

Comment: Since I am printing out a lot of information in my simulation, I have been using printf, because that seems a little faster than ```std::cout <<```. However, std::cout should be fine in this case @user17732522

Comment: @Eljay Ignoring the fundamental problem doesn't make it go away.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `printf` is the fundamental problem in this case. If you use `std::cout`, then you use operator overloading to pick the correct one regardless of the type.

Comment: Google for "C++  format library" for alternatives to `printf` and `std::cout`.

Comment: "*The idiomatic C++ way is to ... use `std::cout`*" - in C++20, there is now [`std::format()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) too. (or [`fmt::format()`](https://fmt.dev)), eg: `std::cout << std::format("\n\nTime taken for simulation: {} milliseconds\n", duration.count() );`

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to unconditionally convert to `long long`:

```
long long count = duration.count();
printf("%lld", count);
```

On the other hand, I recommend avoiding `printf` and its footguns.

Comment: ... or: `printf("%lld", (long long)(duration.count()));`

Comment: @MartinRosenau I recommend avoiding C-style casts. They turn simple typos into silent bugs.

Comment: Use `static_cast` instead: `printf("%lld", static_cast<long long>(duration.count()));`

Comment: With this solution, you have to keep all of your `printf()` instructions in synch regarding the type and specifier used.

Comment: @einpoklum You always have to keep the format specifier and the argument in sync. That's the cost of using `printf`. Since we are in control of the argument type in this example, it cannot vary between systems.

Comment: @eerorika: I meant, keep different printf invocations in sync.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(Assuming you *need* to use `printf()`)</sub>

Couple your type definition with a specifier definition:

```
typedef my_duration_t std::chrono::duration<long long, std::milli>;
#define MY_DURATION_SPECIFIER "%lld"
```

and then you write:

```
auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<my_duration_t> (stop-start);
printf(
    "\n\nTime taken for simulation: " MY_DURATION_SPECIFIER " milliseconds\n",
    duration.count() 
);
```

this (ugly) approach is the one used in `stdint.h` for the size-specific integer specifiers:

```
printf("Easy as " PRId64 "!\n", ((int64_t) 123));
```

see also [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Answer (score 0):

There are [format macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes#Macros) for many types if you `#include <cinttypes>`, but it appears [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) doesn't have a macro.

You might consider using string stream:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << duration.count();
printf("%s", ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: "*it appears `std::chrono::duration` doesn't have a macro*" - It is not `duration` itself that is being formatted, but its `count()` value instead, and that will certainly have a type covered by the `<cinttypes>` macros, eg: `printf("\n\nTime taken for simulation: " PRIdLEAST64 " milliseconds\n", (int_least64_t) duration.count() );`

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's not using a macro for the type returned by `duration.count()`, that's casting the type, not any different from casting to `long long` or something.

Comment: `std::chrono::milliseconds` is defined to use a "signed integer type of at least 45 bits", so could be a `long` or a `long long` depending on the compiler, and those types use different macros in `<cinttypes>`. Hence the cast to a more common 64bit integer type, of which there is a macro for. Otherwise, you would have to detect the `count()` type at compile-time and code accordingly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: "so could be a long or a long long depending on the compiler" <- it could theoretically be something different than either of those, couldn't it?

Comment: @einpoklum "*it could theoretically be something different than either of those, couldn't it?*" - yes, it could be whatever the `<chrono>` implementation wants to use, as long as it satisfies the size requirement. Hence the cast to a compatible type that the coder decides on.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Assuming you need to use `printf()`)</sub>

Use an intermediate `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "\n\nTime taken for simulation: " << duration.count() << "\n";
printf("%s",ss.str().c_str());
// or instead of the last line: puts(ss.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using std::cout in all cases.

With regards to speed difference between the two, consider using:

```
std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

at the beginning of your code. This only works if you replace all your printf/scanf (and the like) usage with their C++ alternatives.

Using this should make the speed difference go away.